# any code make sure json fully added to canvas?

Tags: fabricjs

```
var json = [];

json.push(json2);

function makeallImage(){
    console.log('json length'+json.length);
    for (var v = 0; v < json.length; v++){
        convertImgToBase64(v, "jpg");
        console.log("ksana"+v);
    }
}

function convertImgToBase64(number, outputFormat){  
var tmpData = 
canvas.loadFromJSON(json[number], canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(){
    **//need to absolute comfirm it add all object in canvas, load complete json2 //**
    canvas.on('object:added', function(e) {
    toImg();
    });
    });
}

function toImg(outputFormat){
    var s = document.getElementById("last_Image");
    var url = canvas.toDataURL();
    var newImg = document.createElement("img"); // create img tag
    console.log(newImg);
    newImg.src = url;
    newImg.width = 100;
    newImg.height = 100;
    s.appendChild(newImg);
    console.log('mpike sto dom');
}
```

i am using this code to create image to field , problem is if my json object contain image ,it will create empty image. so i figure it out is because loading the src need time and canvas create image before it fully load.

i need to make sure the json fully loaded on canvas first , so i found a fabric code call object:added , which can make sure object added in canvas , but it count object one by one , so if my json cotain 2 object it will create more image.

achievement
1. i need to make sure my json fully load or create in canvas before create image , is they any way to make sure json fully added to canvas?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/v1nmtz02/1/) see my problem using object:added it load multiple image.

Answer (score 1):

You should dump reviver and use just the callback function.

http://jsfiddle.net/v1nmtz02/2/

You will have some difficulties with fabricImages and objects that have a content that is async. That is not yet solved at library level.

```
function _callback() {
  canvas.renderAll();
  toImg();
}

function convertImgToBase64(number, outputFormat){  
var tmpData = canvas.loadFromJSON(json[number], _callback);
}
```

Complete snippet:

```js
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var json2 = '{"objects":[{"type":"circle","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":400,"width":200,"height":200,"fill":"rgb(166,111,213)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"#5b238A","blur":20,"offsetX":-20,"offsetY":-10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"radius":100},{"type":"rect","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":500,"width":150,"height":150,"fill":"#fbb802","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"rgba(94, 128, 191, 0.5)","blur":5,"offsetX":10,"offsetY":10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0}],"background":""}';



var json = [];

json.push(json2);

function makeallImage(){
for (var v = 0; v < json.length; v++){
 convertImgToBase64(v, "jpg");
}
}

function _callback() {
  canvas.renderAll();
  toImg();
}

function convertImgToBase64(number, outputFormat){ 
var tmpData = canvas.loadFromJSON(json[number], _callback);
}

function toImg(outputFormat){
var s = document.getElementById("last_Image");
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = url;
newImg.width = 100;
newImg.height = 100;
s.appendChild(newImg);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="550" height="550" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
<button onclick="makeallImage();">makepng</button>
<div id="last_Image" style="background:red"></div>
```